# What is the correct reading of 折 in "裏面那根麥管給咬折了"?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm having trouble judging when 折 is 折 shé and when it is zhé. Is there any simple rule to this?

In the book I'm reading, I've encountered the following phrase.

> 裏面那根麥管給咬折了。

The Guifan says the following:

> 注意 ㊀跟“拆”不同。㊁表示“断”时, 读zhé, 多侧重于行为本身, 可带宾语, 如“折桂”“折戟沉沙”; 读shé, 多侧重于行为结果, 不可独立带宾语, 如“鞭子打折了”“撞折了小树”; 读zhē, 指翻转､倾倒(dào), 如“折腾”。

However, scanning different dictionary entries, there seems to be more to it than this. For example, why is it 拉折 lā shé, but 攀折 pānzhé?

Answer (score 1):

The pronunciation of "折" in "裏面那根麥管給咬折了" should be [shé] (see  "method 2b" below for explanation and examples.

"折" can be pronounced 3 ways, the meaning and use of each are as follows:

1. [zhē] - 翻转(retroflexion, tumbling). Ex: 折跟头
2. [shé] - a) 亏损(loss, deficit, negative profit). Ex: 折本生意. **b)** 断(broken). Ex: 绳子折(断)了;  **拉折(断)**
3. [zhé] - 弄断(break off). Ex: **攀折**

https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%8A%98

Comment: Thank you. This might seem like a dumb question, but why does "拉折" not mean "to pull something so that it breaks" (and therefore la1zhe2), but rather that something is already broken? Both 拉折 and 攀折 seem to be two verb morphemes (拉[pull]+折[break] / 攀[climb]+折[break]) combined into new verbs.

Comment: Good question. I think the sound 折[shé] was used in phrases that were prevalent in some locals rather than standard expressions, for example - 腿打折了(local), 腿打**斷(殘)**了(std); 折本生意(local), **蝕(陪)**本生意(std). Following this explanation, 攀折 can be seen as the standard expression of the local usage - 拉折, so the difference in sound. Note the explanation above is my personal view only.

Answer (score 1):

“裏面那根麥管給咬折了。”
表示弯曲的时候读zhé。
“why is it 拉折 lā shé, but 攀折 pānzhé?”
“㊁表示“断”时, 读zhé, 多侧重于行为本身” = break
"读shé, 多侧重于行为结果, 不可独立带宾语” = be broken
拉折: pull something broken  e.g. 我把树枝拉折了。
攀折: pull and break something   e.g. 请勿攀折树枝。
攀有拉的意思，多用于书面语，攀折也是一个固定的书面用词。
拉折更像是口语用词。

我不是专业人士，仅供参考，如有专业人士以他们的意见为准。

Comment: This sounds like it could be the correct answer. I'm still having trouble understanding why "我把树枝拉折了" should be shé though. To my mind both sentences imply that someone is actively breaking something. I'm waiting for more answers before I mark this as the answer. Is it because of the 把?

Comment: Sorry. I've tried but It's hard for me to make further explanations. Let's wait for more experienced people to answer.